# Linking online databases to a project for iOS

Tags: ios, database

I'm working on an iOS app for having a list of top 10 of everything. 
So the problem I'm facing is how do I update the list every week ?
I thought of linking it to external links but then I was unable to format the webpage according to the interface of my app. 
Lastly I want the app not only to display the top 10 list but also to be able to interact. For example if the user enters into top 10 songs then he should be able to play the tracks as well ! So for this I guess I'll be needing a database which I could update weekly. I don't know how to go about this. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

You need a remote server, running with an application that handles the list generation/updates, and you will probably need also to manage a remote database, if you expect that the number of item will be reasonably large.

Your ios application will have to interact with your remote server using an API that you will have to define as well.

I'm sorry to be that generic, but the hard truth is that there is no quick or easy way to do it: you will need to learn and possibly develop every part of your system and then integrate them.

You have nearly an infinite number of options in terms of platforms/languages/databases to choose from, for the backend part.

Over the last few years, there have been services that should make handling the remote backend  easier (Stackmob, cloudbase...) but it really depends on much control you want to have on the "lists" you want to manage.